# Why does $(element).parent() find the parent Node, but javascript element.parentNode return undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just found an... oddity? ... in one of our scripts. In the method, we have the following javascript snippet:

```
        if (inside)
            elem.insertBefore(c, null);
        else
            elem.parentNode.insertBefore(c, elem.nextSibling);
```

when using the console with the following commands (in chrome), I get the following results:

Javascript:

`elem.parentNode -> undefined`

Jquery

```
$(elem).parent(); -> <div class="btn-holder-right"><input onclick=" return handle_qa_submit_comment(5, 6, this);" value="Submit Comment" title="" type="submit" class="btn btn-community"></div>
```

I find this behaviour odd and want to know why this occurs. Any advice?

First - The button's `onclick` handler sends the button itself to the function listed in the `onclick` event

```
<input onclick=" return handle_qa_submit_comment(5, 6, this);" value="Submit Comment" title="" type="submit" class="btn btn-community">
```

The function contains some ajax which does a couple of things on our site, like submitting a comment

```
function handle_qa_submit_comment(postId, parentPostId, elem){
    var ajaxUrl = '../forum/qa-include/app/handler.php';
    var data = { 
                    action : 'add_comment',
                    data :
                    {
                        'postId' : postId,
                        'parentPostId' : parentPostId,
                    }
                };
    try
    {               
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            async: true, 
            type: 'POST'
        }).done(function(jqxhr,textStatus){
            if (jqxhr !== 'true' && textStatus !== 'success'){
                return handle_qa_submit_comment_failed(403, null);
            }
            else {
                qa_submit_comment(postId, parentPostId, $(elem)); // calls 
            }
        }).error(function(){
            return handle_qa_submit_comment_failed(404, null);
        });
    }
    catch (exception)
    {
        return handle_qa_submit_comment_failed(500, exception); 
    }
}
```

When the ajax is done:

```
function qa_submit_comment(questionid, parentid, elem)
{
   ...do stuff...
   qa_show_waiting_after(elem, false);
}
```

Finally:

```
function qa_show_waiting_after(elem, inside)
{
    var c = 'some html....';
    if (elem && !elem.qa_waiting_shown) {

            if (inside)
                elem.insertBefore(c, null);
            else
                elem.parentNode.insertBefore(c, elem.nextSibling); // fail here because elem.parentNode is undefined. when I test $(elem).parent() it finds the actual parent.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you post how elem is initialized?  It might be that the element is not yet in the DOM, e.g you are constructing the HTML within JQuery, and it has its own representation of the DOM until its actually inserted into the DOM?

Comment: You asked for it. it's a series of method calls which ends up at `qa_show_waiting_after`  where `elem` definitely contains the button, parentNode displays `undefined` and `$(elem).parent()`, typed directly into the console when breakpoint is on elem.parentNode.insertbefore() actually returns the element's parent node. Also, I omitted some sensitive code from prying eyes of the public :)

Comment: tried to prevent posting a wall-of-code

Comment: I did ask for it :)  And it highlighted the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qa_submit_comment(postId, parentPostId, $(elem)); // calls
```

Your elem reference in qa_submit_comments is a JQuery reference, not a DOM element.  Try passing $(elem) through without the $(...) e.g:

```
qa_submit_comment(postId, parentPostId, elem); // calls
```

Or unwrap it in the function qa_submit_comment

```
elem = elem[0];  // unwrap JQuery object to real element
```

Also, there is probably a bug here (not 100% though)

```
if (elem && !elem.qa_waiting_shown)
```

Depending on how you set qa_qaiting_shown in the first place, this might always be evaluating to false, as it could be on the DOM element or the JQuery element, its probably on your DOM element though.  I would test this condition a little more.

Comment: `"Your elem reference in qa_submit_comments is a JQuery reference, not a DOM element. Try passing $(elem) through without the $(...) e.g:"` That did it. I removed the JQuery part around the `elem`, and the loader is appearing again. I was unaware that JQuery References don't work exactly the same way as a DOM element

Comment: Yea, its a wrapper object containing the JQuery functionality.  You can unwrap them as I suggested.  Also, I would look into the elem.qa_waiting_shown part of the if statement, there *might* be a bug there

Comment: The bug is also not a bug, because there are way way much more code before the line you highlighted where `elem.qa_waiting_shown` is initialized with a cloned node.

Comment: Yea, if you are accessing the elem correctly, it is probably fixed as well.

Comment: Well, I marked your answer as correct :) thank you, it worked just fine. it was only that annoying little $(...). Thank heavens for a blame feature on SVN - I'm to find the culprit and make him pay for that